# How can I count the number of times a button is pressed while an item is selected from a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

The List Box has three candidates and a record Button.  Every time the record button is hit I need it to add those button clicks for each candidate that is selected in the List Box.  My code keeps counting all the clicks no matter which candidate I am selecting in the List Box.  How can I differentiate between each selected item in the List Box.

Here is an image of how the application should look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7TSJ.jpg

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub exitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Dim candidatevotes(2) As Integer
    Dim vote
    Dim total

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        candListBox.Items.Add("Mark Stone")
        candListBox.Items.Add("Sheima Patel")
        candListBox.Items.Add("Sam Perez")
        candListBox.SelectedIndex = 0

    End Sub
    Private Sub recordButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles recordButton.Click

        candidatevotes(vote) = candListBox.SelectedIndex

        total += candidatevotes(vote)


        Dim outfile As IO.StreamWriter
        outfile = IO.File.AppendText("voteinfo.txt")
        outfile.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(candListBox.SelectedItem))
        outfile.Close()

    End Sub
    Private Sub displayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles displayButton.Click


        Dim infile As IO.StreamReader

        If IO.File.Exists("voteinfo.txt") = True Then
            infile = IO.File.OpenText("voteinfo.txt")

            infile.Close()
        End If


        markLabel.Text = total.ToString
        sheimaLabel.Text = total.ToString
        samLabel.Text = total.ToString


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
candidatevotes(vote) = candListBox.SelectedIndex
total += candidatevotes(vote)
```

should be

```
candidatevotes(candListBox.SelectedIndex) += 1
```

and

```
markLabel.Text = total.ToString
sheimaLabel.Text = total.ToString
samLabel.Text = total.ToString
```

should be

```
markLabel.Text = candidatevotes(0)
sheimaLabel.Text = candidatevotes(1)
samLabel.Text = candidatevotes(2)
```